# Оповещение о новой правке

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Интересует почему не реализовали оповещение о том, что необходимо проверить первое сообщение, запоздалый ответ и т.п. Возьмите пример с почты mail.ru. У меня постоянно открыта вкладка с почтой и видно, что приходят новый сообщения по самой иконке (она немного меняет цвет) и не нужно постоянно заходить и проверять, пришло что-то или нет.

Предлагаю тоже самое сделать и с проверками, сидишь, ждёшь и неизвестно, нужно что-то проверить или нет, потому что необходимо сделать 2 действия, от которых можно полностью избавиться.
1. Перейти на открытую вкладку с проверками.
2. Обновить страницу.

Только после этих действий лично у меня актуализируется информация. Хочу большее количество постов/сообщений в день проверять, а бегать между вкладками в надежде, что, может, уже пришла какая-то проверка - не очень удобно. Не знаю, зависит это от браузере или нет, но в Firefox это действует именно так.

Comment: Зачем бегать? Просто несколько раз в день заходить в очередь и проверять.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica а что, если хочу чаще проверять и в пустую не тратить время на проверку того, есть новые проверки или нет.

Comment: @Blacit, у меня есть подозрение, что есть скрипт, позволяющий получать такие оповещения. Иначе не представляю, как за полдня можно сделать 20 проверок, например, на предлагаемые правки (нормальным способом - это весь день сидеть и постоянно обновлять страницу проверки): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats

Comment: @insolor Наверно надо у корифеев очередей проверок спросить:  0xdb, aleksandr barakin.

Comment: Так вроде и тут наличие сообщений в очереди проверок вполне отображается: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyMkL.png
Или речь о чем-то другом?

Comment: @Yaant, допустим, у вас цель нафармить значки Инспектора и Ревизора по всем очередям. Проблема в том, что в некоторых очередях сообщения для проверки появляются очень редко, и прежде чем ты увидишь что в очереди что-то есть (если будешь, например, раз в час проверять наличие объектов для проверки в очереди), эту проверку уже выполнит кто-то другой.

Comment: @insolor Поэтому и предлагаю делать не скрипт самому, а чтобы разработчики позаботились. Потому что значки фармить очень долго придётся, при условии, что кто-то может со скриптом, а кто-то нет.

Comment: @Blacit, большинству участников нет дела до проверок и до значков (как было сказано в удаленном сейчас ответе), лишние уведомления будут только нервировать. Вряд ли кто-то будет подстраиваться под тех кто целенаправленно фармит значки - сообществу важно чтобы очереди оперативно обрабатывались, а не то чтобы отдельные участники получали значки.

Comment: @insolor Оповещение позволяет более быстро реагировать всем пользователям на возможные правки и подобное. Понимаете же ведь сами, что вместо необходимого обновления страницы раз в час, пользователь будет заходить туда по необходимости (когда будет появляться оповещение), которая действительно появилась, а не возможной, которую ожидает пользователь во время обновления страницы. Что нам дают уведомления: 1. Ещё более быстрое решение правок. 2. Нет необходимости делать велосипеды с помощью скриптов. 3. Если человек хочет нафармить значок, то он в равной ситуации с остальными людьми